# How to handle word splits in Speech Recognitions in Android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am trying to implement the speech recognition in android.

Here I have a paragraph set to TextView.
I have array list of words split by " " blank space.
I am using onPartialResult to get words spoken by user.
we get input words like this

```
[I]
[I am]
[I am android]
[I am android user]
```

so i am converting that to arraylist of words by splitting by space
and taking only last element of array. so every time i will get only new word.

now on getting new word i have to match it with arraylist of words from paragraph.

I have a global index which keeps increasing on matching.
also on matching i take indexs in paragraph text of TextView using spannable.
Then set color to that matched word.

Spannable text and textview text content should be same so that we can apply color correctly. so while matching we cant modify the texts of paragraph we used to display.

This is code i am using right now

```java
  private void applyColor(String param){
        ArrayList<String> params = paraToArray(param);
        // from string only get last word
        String newWord = params.get(params.size()-1);
        // get current word of paragraph by using global index tracking 
        String currentWord_FromParagraph = paragraphWords.get(indexHistory);

        // handle 's words
        if(currentWord_FromParagraph.contains("'s")){
            String rootWord = currentWord_FromParagraph.replaceAll("'s\\b", "");
            newWord = rootWord+"'s";
        }
        
        // index of word on paragraph
        int start = paragraph.indexOf(newWord, indexHistoryChar);
        int end = newWord.length();
        
        // match
        if(start != -1 && newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(currentWord_FromParagraph) ){
            // spannable contains paragraph and its global 
             spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), start, 
             start+end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            // global index for array of words of paragraph. after matching ignore current index so we look for next word
            indexHistory++;
            // similar as above but it is for paragraph character index
            indexHistoryChar = start+end;


            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), startNext, endNext, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        }

        txtv_paragraph.setText(spannableString);

    }
```

**The problem:
while speaking some words like 'carefree' recognition returns care free which leads to having two elements [care, free] so this makes matching words improper.**
Although sometime it detects carefree andgives single word carefree but most of time it returns care free. how can we handle this issue in android?

What would be the good solution for detection and matching words.

initial thoughts came into mind which is scary and does not seems sensible.
that if I check paragraph's wordarray 'carefree' contains care then next check carefree contains free then check previouse and current index care and free are not same then concat them and match. and get postion to change its color in TextView.

Another things I am expecting if there is any algorithm or library which can handle this.

Please share your opinions

Answer (score 1):

Put your paragraph in a Trie data structure. Use some Trie helper classes example [this](https://geekyisawesome.blogspot.com/2012/07/java-trie.html)

Don't put any spaces in the speech recognize by the system (let's say 'Iamandroiduser') and pass one by one character to the Trie structure until Trie no longer find any possible match. Check [this example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/238082/57259) as well.

I haven't tried this but giving you another idea.